# How to view this custom option in another phtml file in Magento2?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

which way we have to override this position in custom option to view in another phtml file.
[image]

added this code in checkout_cart_index.xml which is override only the form.phtml not override the default.phtml file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<!-- <update handle="checkout_cart_item_renderers"/> -->
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.form">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Bespoke_Bespoke::cart/form.phtml</argument>
            </action>
    </referenceBlock> 
     <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Bespoke_Bespoke::cart/item/default.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

i am getting error regarding the 'checkout.cart.item.renderers' already has a child with alias 'simple' i have modify that file of checkout_cart_item_renderer.xml

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<!-- <update handle="checkout_item_price_renderers"/> -->
<body>
  <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.form">
<action method="setOverriddenTemplates">
    <argument xsi:type="array">
        <!-- list override templates -->
        <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Bespoke_Bespoke::cart/item/default.phtml</item>
        <item name="simple" xsi:type="string">Bespoke_Bespoke::cart/item/default.phtml</item>
        <item name="virtual" xsi:type="string">Bespoke_Bespoke::cart/item/default.phtml</item>
    </argument>
  </action>
  </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

to override the file we use to etc/di.xml

```
 <config  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\AbstractCart" type="AGS\Bespoke\Block\Checkout\Cart\AbstractCart"/><preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Option" type="AGS\Bespoke\Block\Product\View\Option"/>
   <preference for=" Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" type="AGS\Bespoke\Block\Checkout\Cart"/>
   <preference for="\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" type="AGS\Bespoke\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer"/>
   <virtualType name="AGS\Bespoke\Model\ResourceModel\Bespoke\Bespoke\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">     
  <arguments><argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">ags_bespoke</argument><argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">AGS\Bespoke\Model\ResourceModel\Bespoke</argument> 

  </arguments></virtualType><type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
<arguments><argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
<item name="bespoke_record_bespoke_list_data_source" xsi:type="string">AGS\Bespoke\Model\ResourceModel\Bespoke\Bespoke\Collection</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way the attributes displayed in the product view pay may vary a lot from theme to theme.
But if you are using a theme similar to the default theme (before 1.9) here is what you can do.

Look for this in the `catalog.xml` of your theme:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
</block>
```

and remove the line `<action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>`. That's the line responsible for placing the block in a specific group.

Then edit `catalog/product/view.phtml` and add this line where you want the attributes to be displayed.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional')?>
```

If you are using a theme similar to the rwd theme (the 1.9 default one) you should do this:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
</block>
```

You should to the same thing as above. But in addition also remove this line

```
<action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
```

Comment: we are looking the answer in magento 2 @LuFFy.